# How to add formula to cells using VBA, with reference cell being dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am trying to add a formula to 40 cells in a columns. It is a custom built formula that pulls data from local network. I am using the folloing VBA code.

```
For j = 1 To 40
Cells(j, 4) = "=Ark(""GetRD"",C1&"" Corp"",""ISSUER"")"
Next j
```

Here, column C contains unique reference data using which the function gives an output.
What code should be used so that the reference cell changes with every iteration?

Thank you!!

Comment: Perhaps: `Cells(j, 4).Resize(40).FormulaR1C1 = "=Ark(""GetRD"",RC3&"" Corp"",""ISSUER"")"` with no loop.

Comment: I tried the code line. But, it is giving an error. I am not sure how .FormulaR1C1 and RC3 are working here.

Comment: Put the correct formula manually into cell D1, then in the Immediate Window in the VB Editor, enter: `?Range("D1").Formular1c1` and press enter, and let us know the output.

Comment: If memory serves, you can achieve this with the [`Range.Filldown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown) Method.

Comment: the output is as follows  =Ark("GetRD",RC[-1]&" Corp","ISSUER")